# vscodeにて、CSSの影響範囲一覧を確認する方法はありますか？

Tags: html, css, vscode, xpath

vscodeにて、CSSの影響範囲一覧を確認する方法はありますか？

cssを編集する際に、ワークスペース全体で
どこまで影響があるかを簡易的に確認する方法はないでしょうか。

例えば下記cssの記述があったとして
クラス名がclass15であり、子要素にspanの記述がある箇所全てを
1つのhtmlファイル内に限らず、プロジェクト全体から
一覧で確認する方法、拡張機能などがあれば教えて頂ければと思います。

```css
.class15 span {
    color: #F00;
}
```

ネットで探してみたところ、xpathという言葉に出会いましたが
vscode、HTML・CSSでは使用できなそうな気がしました。

（最悪、vscodeを使わない手段でも構いません。）

以上、宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: マルチポスト: https://teratail.com/questions/194841

Answer (score 1):

確かにご質問の一覧が表示できると良いなと思い探してみました。

CSS Navigationという拡張の「Find All References」という機能が使えると思います。
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=pucelle.vscode-css-navigation

と、思ったのですが、「影響範囲」を調べるという意味では全然足りないですね。すみません。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]